# Yii 2 restful api custom param

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am using Yii 2 to create a Restful API. Til now I am able to get all products from the database as shown.

```
   [
        {
            "product_id": 28,
            "model": "Product 1",
            "date_modified": "2011-09-30 01:05:39"
        }
    ]
```

The problem with this is i cannot access the details of a single product using the `product_id` which is the primary key in my case.
How do map my URLs so that I can access single product details using 
`index.php?r=products/product_id` unlike Yii 2 default which would be `index.php?r=products/id`  Below is my UrlManager Configs

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'product/<product_id:\d+>' => 'product/view',
            ],
  ],
```

Comment: not clear if you are extending you controllers from `yii\rest\ActiveController`  or `yii\rest\Controller`

Comment: I'm using `yii\rest\ActiveController`